# Unity GameManager not destroying itself and creating a new instance on main scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am creating a new game but my game is not loading when I start my main scene.

```
    private void Awake()
        {
            if (GameManager.instance != null)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
                Debug.Log("Destroyed");
                return;            
            } 

            instance = this;
            SceneManager.sceneLoaded += LoadState;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
```

This is not running when I start the Main Scene, the console shows, also the debug for LoadState is also not triggering.

Helps are appreciated.

I tried debugging, but the loadstate is not running.

The game is suppose to load the state right when the scene start, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

I am still really new to all this so please bare with me.

Comment: Is this in your game manager? if so first obvious thing is just refer to "instance" not gamemanager.instance" .  You said loadstate isnt running, by the time that first game object runs and makes your gamemanager, scene is already loaded..

Answer (score 0):

`LoadState` is not running because at the moment this `Awake` is called for the first time the scene is already loaded.

Simply call it yourself once

```
 private void Awake()
 {
    if (GameManager.instance != null)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Destroyed");
        return;            
    } 

    instance = this;
    SceneManager.sceneLoaded += LoadState;
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}

// I would do it in Start so other Awake are finished by now
private void Start()
{
    // assuming as you say this is the first main scene it is probably always loaded as single
    LoadState(SceneManager.GetActiveScene(), LoadSceneMode.Single);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out and it was such a stupid mistake.

I simply had to go into Unity Editor Preferences and change the Editor settings so that it would load the scene when entering Play Mode. Not sure why this setting was off but it solved the problem I had.